# Troubleshooting for loop - problems with sum

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Im taking a C programming beginning course, and have a problem with a for loop.

I want to make two *double* arrays. One that takes input from user, and one that sums the inputs.
I then want to output the two arrays. One that shows the input, and one that shows the sums og the input in every cell.

The problem comes when I try to show the sum for every "cell" in the array.
The output just becomes the same as the input.
I can solve it with:

```
// print all the numbers in the second array
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     sum = sum + a[i];
       printf("%lf ", sum);
```

but then the assignment wouldn't be solved. Hope you can educate me.

```
#include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {

int n; //numbers of cells
int i; //The numbers in the cells


printf("How many cells in the array would you like? \n");
scanf("%d", &n);


double a[n], sum=0; // declare an array and a loop variable.
double b[n], sumo=0;

printf("Enter the numbers:\n");


for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { // read each number from the user
    scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
}

printf("The results, my lord:\n");

// print all the numbers in the first array
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%lf ", a[i]);

}
printf("\n"); //THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM STARTS
// print all the numbers in the second array
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     b[i] = b[i] + a[i];
       printf("%lf ", b[i]);
   }

return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why do you need the 2nd array? Isn't the goal just to sum the elements in the first array?

Answer (score 0):

For starters the array `b` is not initialized

```
double b[n], sumo=0;
```

So this statement

```
b[i] = b[i] + a[i];
```

invokes undefined behavior.

It seems what you need is the following for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  b[i] = a[i];
  if ( i != 0 ) b[i] += a[i-1];
    printf("%lf ", b[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried your way and it worked fine. I did however solve it another way. You can see the results in the comment. :-)

Comment: `b[i] += a[i-1];` --> `b[i] += b[i-1];` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the sum (aka the `b` array) when you read the user data:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    if (i == 0)
    {
        b[i] = a[i];
    }
    else
    {
        b[i] = b[i-1] + a[i];
    }
}
```

or do it like:

```
scanf("%lf", &a[0]);
b[0] = a[0];
for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
{
    scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    b[i] = b[i-1] + a[i];
}
```

or do it like:

```
sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{
    scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
    sum += a[i];
    b[i] = sum;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I tried your way and it worked fine. I did however solve it another way. You can see the results in the comment. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The last part is how I solved the problem. I found the issue that. I didn't update the "sum" for ever loop. It adds a new value in b[I] this way. :-)

```
double a[n], sum=0; // declare an array and a loop variable.
double b[n];

printf("Enter the numbers:\n");


for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { // read each number from the user
    scanf("%lf", &a[i]);
}

printf("The results, my lord:\n");

// print all the numbers in the first array
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%.2lf ", a[i]);

}
printf("\n");
// print all the numbers in the second array
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
     sum = sum + a[i];
     b[i] = sum;
       printf("%.2lf ", b[i]);
```